# Suggested users to follow SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

I'm trying to come up with an SQL query to suggest followers to a user based on the user they just followed. I think the best way to do this would be to find all the accounts followed by the same people that follow the just-followed user (and that the current user does not already follow) based on the Twitter follower model. I think this could be achieved by some sort of `JOIN`

My database tables

**users**

`id|name|username`

**relationships**

`user_id|follows_user_id`

They way following works in my app is:
A record is added to the relationships table with the `user_id` being the ID of the logged in user, and the `follows_user_id` being the id of the user they follow.

Comment: What does the id column do in the second table?

Comment: @Strawberry Nothing of importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u, relationships r
WHERE u.id = r.follows_user_id AND r.user_id = N
```

Where N is the id of the user they just followed.